# Overwrite value in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have to update  test.txt with new values  i,e. delete value {"AAA":"777" , "BBB":"888"} and add {"ABC:"123","GHN:"246"} in tag
but my script append the value  as {"AAA":"777" , "BBB":"888"} {"ABC:"123","GHN:"246"

```
    strFile="test.txt"
Const ForAppending  = 8
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForAppending , True)
objFile.Write("{")
Dim dict
Set dict= CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add "ABC","123"
dict.Add "GHN","246"
k=dict.Keys
v=dict.Items
For j=0 to dict.Count-1
        objFile.Write(chr(34)&k(j)&":"&chr(34)&v(j)&chr(34)&",")
Next
```

==============

Test.txt

```
   [Valid]
   api = https://test.com
   Alpha = FALSE
   tag = {"AAA":"777" , "BBB":"888"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the dictionary object/don't know how, so this may not be a viable solution for you depending on whether you need certain things that the object provides... but without resorting to regex, could you not simply do something like this?

```
Dim fso, filecontent, file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
file = "C:\temp\test.txt"
filecontent = fso.OpenTextFile(file, 1, False).ReadAll
filecontent = Replace(filecontent,  "{""AAA"":""777"" , ""BBB"":""888""}", "{""ABC:""123"",""GHN:""246""}")
fso.OpenTextFile(file, 2, True).Write filecontent
```